# is there a way to query range when maximal range is defined by an array with two numbers

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I need to write an elastic range query that operates on a following index format

```
    ...
    "facetProperties": {
      "fid641616": [
        31.75,
        44.45
      ]
    }
    ...
```

the following query works only if `lt` or `gt` matches the lower or the upper bound of the max range. As soon as I try to narrow both ends, there are no results.

```
    {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [{
            "range": {
              "facetProperties.fid641616": {
                "gt": 33,
                "lt": 42
              }
            }
          }]
        }
      },
      "from": 0,
      "size": 250,
      "sort": [

      ],
      "aggs": {

      },
      "_source": "facetProperties.fid641616"
    }
```

Is there a way to get this working without modifying the index?

update1 - some use cases:
query range:

```
    "range": {
              "facetProperties.fid641616": {
                "gt": 33,
                "lt": 42
             }
          }

    facet1 : [31] - should not be found
    facet2 : [31,45] - should be found 
    facet1 : [31,32] - should not be found
    facet1 : [44,45] - should not be found
```

Comment: Are there only two values in that array `fid641616` and would they be in `order` like `desc` or `asc`?

Comment: @Kamal yes, there are only two values in the array and they are sorted ´asc´

Comment: Could you check the answer I've posted and let me know if that helps!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically it is not possible to query based on the range or difference of two numbers in an array using conventional DSL queries in ES but you can do that using script.

Below is the document and sample script that should help you.

### Sample Document:

```
POST range_index/_doc/1
{
  "array": [31.75, 44.45]
}
```

### Query:

```
POST range_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "script": {
      "script": {
        "source": """
          List list = doc['array'];
          if(list.size()==2){
            long first_number = list.get(0);
            long last_number = list.get(1);

            if(params.gt < first_number)
              return false;

            if(params.lt > last_number)
              return false;

            if((last_number - first_number) >= (params.lt - params.gt))
              return true;
          }
          return false;
        """,
        "params": {
          "gt": 33,
          "lt": 42
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What I've done is simply created a script that would return you documents having the difference of `gt` and `lt` that you have mentioned in your query.

You should be able to view the document I've mentioned in the result. Note that I'm assuming that the field `array` would be in `asc` order.

Basically it would return all the documents having **difference of** **42-33** i.e. **9**.

Let me know if that helps!

Comment: yes, there are max two values, sometimes it can be only one. When there are two of them, they are sorted ´asc´. If there is only one then it must be checked it appears between the two numbers provided by the range query. If there are to numbers, it means that the query range must lay within those two. hope it makes sense. I will update my question and add some use cases to make things more clearer.

Comment: Sure, and I'm sure that could be done. I'll wait for your details before I update my answer.

Comment: @moor, could you test my solution now and let me know if that is working? I've updated it with some conditions.